# Mean of series of dates and times

Tags: python, string, date, time, series

With pandas I imported a CSV file with all different kind of data. I want to get the mean of a series dates with time (arrival times) and a series times (duration times). How is this possible. I think the problem is to change the series to strings and also the transformation form hh:mm:ss to a real number.

With pandas, my csv file looks as follows:

[CSV file in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OqEC.png)

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

1) Slice out one column of your dataFrame

2) Do a list comprehension to transform the timestamps to seconds since epoch (which will be floats)

3) Calculate the mean

4) Convert back to a datetime

Here it is in one line (plus the imports):

```
import time
import datetime
from statistics import mean
df = # your existing dataFrame

avg_arrival_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(mean([time.mktime(x.timetuple()) for x in df['Arrival_time']]))
```